# Not serializing JSON properly in AngularJS for Django REST Framework backend?

Tags: python, django, angularjs, rest

I'm currently using a single page application in AngularJS with a Django backend. I'm using the Django REST Framework.

I'm currently trying to implement a "place order" function. I'm having a lot of issues with actually having the order being placed. The server returns "400 BAD Request" because the JSON is not being properly formatted in app.js. I'm confused about how I need to format it to accommodate the ManyToMany field that is in the Order model.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Bean(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Bag(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class Buyer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Order(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    filled = models.BooleanField()
    beans = models.ManyToManyField(Bean)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from app.models import Order, Bean, Buyer, Bag


class BeanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bean


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    beans = BeanSerializer(many=True)
    buyer = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('buyer', 'created', 'filled', 'beans')


class BuyerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Buyer


class BagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bag
```

**app.js**

```
logistrate.controller('OrderCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.beans = [];
    $scope.orders = [];
    $scope.buyers = [];

    $scope.getBuyers = function () {
        $http.get('/api/buyer/').success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                console.log(value);
                $scope.buyers.push({
                    id: value.id,
                    name: value.name
                });
            });

            console.log($scope.orders);
        });
    };

    $scope.getOrders = function () {
        $http.get('/api/order/').success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                $scope.orders.push({
                    buyer: value.buyer,
                    created: value.created,
                });
            });
        });
    };


    $scope.addBean = function () {
        $scope.beans.push({
            id: 1,
            type: $scope.beanType
            // twelve: $scope.twelve,
            // five: $scope.five
        });
    };

    $scope.placeOrder = function () {
        var order = {
                'buyer': $scope.buyer,
                'beans': $scope.beans,
                'filled': false,
            };
        console.log(order);
        $http.post('/api/order/', order).success(function () {
            console.log("Order placed");
            $scope.getOrders();
        }).error(function (data, status) {

        });
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should find out what format Angular is posting it as. And then read the docs for REST framework on what it expects.

Comment: Angular posts data in `JSON` format instead of `urlencoded`, like django expects. Maybe Django REST Framework expects same? What about your views?

Comment: you should specify fields for all ModelSerializers, you are missing `created` field on order, $scope.buyer should be primary key value; you must decide how you will reference beans - if they are created before and you should add only foreign keys here or you want create beans all the time - this is unclear